# select box fill textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that allow you to choose option from selectbox.

Each choice should print different text in filed TEXTAREA

What did I do wrong? what should I change?

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<form name="form1">
    <fieldset name="Group1">
        <legend>Group box</legend>Center Title:
        <select name="ctrTitles" id="ctrTitles">
            <option value="1">Corp 1</option>
            <option value="2">Shamrock Gold</option>
            <option value="3">Hensin Way</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        Address 1:
        <textarea name="TextArea1" id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
        <br />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
    var centerLocations = new Array({
        text1: 'some text1'
    }, {
        text2: 'some text2'
    }, {
        text3: 'some text3'
    });

    $('#ctrTitles').change(function() {
        address = $(this).val()
        val = $(":selected", this).index();
        $("#TextArea1").val(centerLocations["text" + address]);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, uhm first I MUST tell you that your indentation and HTML presentation are awful, on top of having <br> tags. Also, it's `.onchange=function() {}`, not `.change(function() {})`.

Comment: `onchange` ???  .. `.change` is perfectly fine

Comment: Eh, I've never seen .change. I'll trust you on this. Sorry.

Comment: It is from the `jQuery` API. This question is tagged with jQuery.

Comment: @Ariane: [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) is a jQuery method, whereas `onchange` is a method of a DOM node/object, which has, itself, been replaced (or is in the process of being replaced) by `addEventListener('change', functionToExecute)`. I fully agree with you on the HTML presentation, though.

Comment: @DavidThomas I seeeeeeee. I totally didn't see that this was jQuery. (Also yeah, from what I've been told, addEventListener isn't "safe" to use yet.)

Comment: Hi there.

I tried to use ".onchange" - doesn't work...

Comment: @Roi Read above. I was mistaken.

Comment: @Ariane: it's not fully cross-browser, yet, and Internet Explorer persists in doing things its own way (`attachEvent()` being their alternative). But it's getting there. Roi: is it just the value from the `select` element you want in the `textarea`, or a 'full address'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the way you are accessing the value you should change to object from array, because you are trying to access an array with the property name which doesn't work that way, you can only use index on array, but you can do it on an object by doing `centerLocations["text" + address]`:

```
var centerLocations = {
    text1: 'some text1',
    text2: 'some text2',
    text3: 'some text3'
};
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBpZ2/)**

2 ways you can do it with array or object.

**using Array(only if your index of option matches that of the array item index)**

```
var centerLocations = [
  'some text1' //you can even get rid of text1, text2 etc..
,  'some text2'
, 'some text3'
 ];

$('#ctrTitles').change(function () {
    $("#TextArea1").val(centerLocations[this.selectedIndex]);

   //with your original structure you would do
   //$("#TextArea1").val(centerLocations[this.selectedIndex]['text'+this.value]);

}).change();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zFhuj/)**

**Using object**

```
var centerLocations = {
    text1: 'some text1',
    text2: 'some text2',
    text3: 'some text3'
};

$('#ctrTitles').change(function () {
    $("#TextArea1").val(centerLocations["text" + this.value]);
}).change();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GWact/)**

Comment: thanks!by the way - is there any better way to right code for what I need?

Comment: @Roi Well if you want to simplify, since "text1", etc. isn't significant, you could use a simple array. `centerLocations[0]="some text1"` for instance. But that doesn't change much.

Comment: @Roi yes you can optimize it a bit and also you can do it in 2 ways using array and using object.

Comment: Well, I realy don't understand much with JAVA SCRIPT. I found this code on the net and modify it.

If it doesn't change much maybe it will be better if I won't change it at all...

Comment: @PSL (first time I'm using @) - can you give the the code for the other way?

Comment: Sure This http://jsfiddle.net/ASvRF/ or http://jsfiddle.net/HzJCn/ i will update my answer. Also do remember to mark as answer if this helped you resolve the issues. :)

Comment: @Roi If you use the array method, change your select option values to 0,1,2 instead of 1,2,3.

Comment: yes, thank you very much!
also first time I mark ANSWER for issue (hope i did it right...)

Comment: Roi, actually I just noticed that PSL used selectedIndex, not selectedValue, so you should be fine with your values as they are.